# customising bootstrap menu issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7

I have created dropdown menus and sub-menus down to 4 levels and so far it is working as expected using a combination of `li` and `ul` elements. The trouble is that some of the menu dropdowns are quite large, so I want to force scrollbars and height to contain the size of the dropdowns on screen.

On my top level dropdown I've added the following style to the css:
`height:300px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow:hidden;`

this has given me the desired effect on the first and second level dropdown (both have scroll bars and sit side by side) on the next level it displays inside the second level's container. when this should also be outside. (my code below doesn't show correctly using the code snippet tool for some reason, but if you place the code locally it shows correctly as far as it goes).

Basically if you take the default way that bootstrap creates menu's and submenus where each submenu appears to the right of the parent and slightly down. My goal is to set the top of each level to the top of the first level menu keeping the height of each level the same with scrollbars when necessary.

```css
body {
  font-family: EvaluateFont, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding-top: 70px;
}  

.navbar {
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    top: -8px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 69px !important;
    border-style: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0;
    float: left !important;
}

.scrollable-menu {
    height: 75px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu { /* This is valid in the browser.*/
    width: max-content;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.dropdown-menu.main {
    top: 161px !important;
    height: 75px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    cursor:auto;
}

li {
    position: static;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
    white-space: nowrap;

    // submenu
    ul.wrapper {
        // position on top of the menu item
        position: absolute;
        // top matches top
        //top: 0;
        // left matches 75% of menu item width
        // left: 75%;
        // show on top of the menu item
        z-index: 10; /*put this to -1 once click state has been implemented (will put it below the scrollbar)*/
        // do not show the submenu by default
        display: none;
    }
    // display the submenu when we hover on the menu item
    &:hover > .wrapper {
        display: block;
        top: 85px !important;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        left: 235px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
li.level-1, li.level-2, ul.level-3 {
    margin-left: -30px;
    
    a {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        clear: both;
    }
}

ul.level-2 > li {
    margin-left: -25px;
}

ul.menu-list {
    background-color:#b200ff;
}

ul.wrapper.level-2 {
    background-color: #ff6a00;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.wrapper.level-3 {
    background-color: #451968;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
   
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> CREATE REPORT
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>                     
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu not-visible"><a href="#" class="dropdown-header"><span class="text">Choose a type of report.</span><i class="fa fa-close pull-right icon-dropdown"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
    
                                <ul class="scrollable-menu menu-list">
                                    <li class="parent level-1" >
                                        <a href="#">report set 1</a>
                                        <ul class="wrapper level-2" role="menu" aria-labelledby="comenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">rep 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">rep 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">rep 3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="parent level-1">
                                        <a href="#">rep set 2</a>
                                        <ul class="wrapper scrollable-menu menu-list level-2">
                                            <li><a href="">rep 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 5</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 6</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">rep 7</a></li>
                                            <li class="parent level-2">
                                                <a href="#">rep 7 sub </a>
                                                <ul class="wrapper menu-list level-3">
                                                    <li><a href="">sub 1</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">sub 2</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">sub 3</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML code is incomplete.

Comment: i have edited the question and added the snippet. please complete that so we can see the situation

Comment: @MajiD ok I've added quite a bit more, but you need to expand to full screen when running your code snippet tool

Comment: much of bootstrap3 is heavily reliant on parent-child relationships, with class being added and removed as necessary to manage the nav system. I would consider creating my own classes to add the scrolling functionality as needed that works in conjunction with the assorted BS3 nav states rather than trying to alter all the combinations off BS3 css that gets applied.  It also makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @MajiD I have made some big changes to the code having figured out the issue to the first level.